# JavaScript / jQuery NetCat

Tags: javascript, jquery, netcat

Is it possible to use Netcat on the client side via JavaScript, jQuery or something similar? Basically I want to do something like the following on the client side:

```
nc <IP> <Port> < <File>
```

or

```
nc 123.456.789.10 9100 < myfile.txt
```

where myfile contains the information I want to pass to the IP.

The reason why I want to do this because the IP address is only accessible from the client's computer.

Comment: Is AJAX a viable option?

Comment: Is it necessary to be a webpage?  Can you just put together a script they can run on their computer?

Comment: It is a web application. The clients log in to our server and generate some data, and we need to send the data back to their devices. This can be done through netcat if the server is on their network. However this is not guarantee. That's why I am looking for a way to implement it on the client side.


It seems that node.js will do the work. However, since node.js is a software package that require to be installed on their OS (rather than a javascript library), so this is not our option.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible in a browser.  There are no browser APIs that allow direct socket connections.